# Does "within 10 years from 12-Aug-2023" refer to before or after that date?

Tags: meaning, time

Does "within 10 years from 12-Aug-2023" mean 10 year interval before 12-Aug-23 or otherwise after that date?

Comment: The use of 'from' suggests that August 12th is the period's start date.

Comment: More usual would be *within 10 years **of** [date]*  or *No later|more than 10 years **from** [date]*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [meaning of 'within 30 days of {a certain date in the future ...}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400620/meaning-of-within-30-days-of-a-certain-date-in-the-future-in-context) Or [Meaning of "within 10 days from when they move"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71750/meaning-of-within-10-days-from-when-they-move)? Or [The meaning of 'Do not drink or eat *within* an hour of taking these pills'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5648/does-within-an-hour-mean-before-after-or-both)? Basically, it's ambiguous, using 'of' (as is usual)

Comment: Or maybe *within 10 years after..* or better still *before 12th august 2033*